# having trouble with react app, eslint version issue , heavily confused, any help appreciated

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, eslint, npm-install

I'm attempting to create a react app for the first time and i'm having issues due to the version of eslint. When I type "npm start" in the terminal, this is the error message I'm receiving:

The react-scripts package provided by Create React App requires a dependency:
"eslint": "^7.11.0"

Don't try to install it manually: your package manager does it automatically.
However, a different version of eslint was detected higher up in the tree:
/Users/karinapichardo/node_modules/eslint (version: 8.2.0)

how do I go about solving this issue? I realize I need the eslint v7, how do I get that version? any help would be greatly appreciated !! First time attempting to use react and just trying to set up my environment.

Comment: you can run this command `npm i eslint@7.11.0` in the terminal to install that specific version

Comment: it's giving me a bunch of warnings saying I have to "install peer dependencies myself" ? @Khabir

Comment: doesn't seem to actually download that specific version , when I run "npm start" the same error message as before pops up

Comment: it is really tough to solve this kind of issue without seeing the actual picture. I suggest you, as you are new, can you please try by following this link https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html

Comment: The path for “higher up in the tree” looks like your user folder. Did you at any point install eslint globally using npm i -g eslint?

Comment: I honestly can't remember @TorRaswill

Comment: when I run "npm ls eslint" I get this message : ── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY eslint@7.11.0 
└─┬ react-scripts@4.0.3
  └── eslint@7.32.0 

npm ERR! peer dep missing: eslint@>=7.28.0, required by eslint-plugin-prettier@4.0.0

Comment: now that I am thinking about it, I think I definitely installed eslint globally when I had no idea what I was doing, how do I remove it? @TorRaswill

Comment: Try running npm uninstall -g eslint, that should uninstall it globally.